# How to get the original service from a wsdl file

Tags: wcf

i have a wsdl file, now i need to get the original wcf service. and after that i want to use(consume) that service in my web project.
please tell me is this possible? and how?

Answer (score 2):

The WSDL contains only the definitions of the service contracts and data contracts. Don't expect to reconstruct the implementation of the original service from a WSDL file. In order to generate a client proxy which will allow you to call the service given this WSDL you could use the [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) utility.